# Installing fricas in LISP

Tags: svn, lisp

I am looking at [the tutorial for installing lisp](http://fricas.sourceforge.net/doc/INSTALL.txt).

I am at the part on "Step by step instructions for first time users:"

I have already used subversion to get the sources. I think I now need to use lisp.

I am told to run the command:

```
 ../fricas/configure --with-lisp=/path/to/your/lisp --prefix=/tmp/usr
```

I don't know what to add as `/path/to/your/lisp`. To obtain lisp I simply used

```
sudo apt-get install clisp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lisp is `/usr/bin/clisp`, you can either use it as is or detect it on the fly using [`which`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_(Unix)):

```
../fricas/configure --with-lisp=$(which clisp) --prefix=/tmp/usr
```

or

```
./configure --with-lisp=/usr/bin/clisp --prefix=/tmp/usr
```

Comment: Sorry, I am really a beginner, I am assuming instead of "../fricas/configure" I should write something else right?

Comment: No, both `../fricas/configure` and `./configure` should work.

Comment: you are very welcome!